# Регулярное выражение для проверки некоторых символов в именах

Tags: php, битрикс

**Доброго времени суток**

В БД есть элементы с определенными названиями, вот в таком ввиде:

```
<name>Электрический краскопульт ЭКП-700В</name>
<name>Дрель-шуруповерт ВИХРЬ ДА-12Л-2</name>
<name>Дрель-шуруповерт ВИХРЬ ДА-12Л-2К</name>
<name>Электрогенератор EUROLUX G1200A</name>
```

И есть csv файл в котором имена вот в таком виде:

```
Краскопульт электрический ЭКП-700В Вихрь 
Дрель-шуруповерт аккумуляторная ДА-12Л-2 Вихрь 
Дрель-шуруповерт аккумуляторная ДА-12Л-2К   
Электрогенератор G 1200 A  Eurolux
```

**Моя задача** проверить имена на совпадения, если true то делаю что то...
Нюансы в **именах:** имена целиком не соотвествую друг другу, но их модели соотвествуют.

Нюансы в **моделях:** если посмотрите то в инфоблоке последний элемент **Электрогенератор EUROLUX G1200A**, у него модель **G1200A**, т.е. все слитно.

А в файле эта же модель имеет вот такой вид, **G 1200 A**, т.е. есть пробелы.
**Вопрос:** Как сделать регуляроное выражение что бы сделать проверку соотвествие моделей в именах, так жу учитывать в моделях пробелы и слитность?
И так же например в инфоблоке в элементе **Электрический краскопульт ЭКП-700В**, т.е. после модели не чего нет.
А в файле в имени "**Краскопульт электрический ЭКП-700В Вихрь**", после наименования модели идет слова **Вихрь**.
Суть вопроса, опять же какое регуляроное выражение составить что бы все вышеперечисленные нюансы учесть и найти соотвествие имен?
Надеюсь я смог донести суть вопроса =). Если что, то спрашивайте что не понятно, я постараюсь донести инфу.

Comment: Вряд ли задача решается регулярным выражением. По сути надо обработать каждую пару - запись из первого списка с записью из второго. Регулярки таким не занимаются. Боюсь, тут надо рисовать собственную процедуру сравнения, и будет она если и не сильно сложной, то уж точно ресурсоёмкой. Впрочем, если под всем этим лежит какая-то БД, то можно накапливать соответствия (точнее, версии написания), и по мере накопления жить будет всё проще.

Comment: @Akina, данные из первого списка находятся в БД.

Comment: Эммм... вот именно в XML? И уж коли в БД -  укажите, какая и какой версии.

Comment: @Akina, БД mysql, версия 15.1. Данные из первого списка находятся в БД, а данные из второго списка, находятся в csv файле.

Comment: *БД mysql, версия 15.1* Нет такой. Последняя - 8.0.17.

Comment: @Akina, я в консоли набрал mysql --version, выдал: mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB, for Win32 (AMD64)

Comment: Ну так у Вас не MySQL, а MariaDB версии 10.1.37. Тогда однозначно хранимая процедура. Либо выполнять операцию на клиенте.